# Get the Google profile picture in Android

Tags: android, image, google-plus

Is it possible currently to get the **Google profile picture** and paint it in an `ImageView`? I've been looking for posts that talk about this but I have not managed to find it.

Comment: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2014/02/migrating-from-plusclient-to.html

Comment: edit the question and post piece of code what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is authenticate and use one of the Google+ OAuth scopes (I think it would be plus.login), to get the profile picture url: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes

You can use the GoogleApiClient for this. Have a look into the documentation. Or take a look into the link in the comments of your question
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html

After that you can use a library like Picasso to load the image from the URL into the ImageView: http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.with(context).load(pictureUrl).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 3):

geting google plus profile pic without using google api key

http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/any_name?alt=json

and after that you can grab img url in json and remove 's64-c'  part from the url and
append "?sz=100" parameter (100 or lager size)

http://lh6.ggpht.com/-gAabIEudGQw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/n062zUtBx4k/s64-c/101417311204099987701.jpg